# Why won't mkdir work on Git Shell or default command prompt (using Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, mkdir, git-shell

I am new to using the command line to add/modify files. I want to be able to make new folders/directories. I cannot figure out why the command "mkdir" won't work on my machine.

I have tried to use the default and Git Shell command prompt. "mkdir" doesn't work on either.

I also have made sure that extensions are enabled on my Registry Editor, which is the only advice I could find on the web that seemed to pertain to me.

I also tried both the "mkdir" and "md" commands that I found on Windows' help sites.

This is what I keep seeing:

```
Hilary@Hilary  ~/Desktop (master)
$ mkdir funny
bash: mkdir: command not found

Hilary@Hilary  ~/Desktop (master)
$ md sad
bash: md: command not found
```

Is there a better command prompt or is there a way I could put this command into the command prompt? Other common commands (like cd and mv) work.

Comment: Thank you. I know command prompt is better in the long run, but the learning curve is steep.